# I only want to show links to categories that have posts in 'publish' state in my menu

Tags: menus, filters, hooks, navigation, api

**I am working on a WordPress project where I want to dynamically filter menu items (and possibly their parent items) based on whether they are associated with any published posts.** Specifically, I am looking to dynamically filter out categories from the menu if they have no association to posts with a "published" state. Furthermore, if a parent category has no children with published posts, that parent category should be dynamically filtered out from the menu as well.

***The updating of the Wordpress navigation block should happen whenever a post is updated.***

1 - **I have been using PHP to query the database and determine whether a category has any published posts associated with it.** I created a function to check each category and its parent category to see if there are any published posts and dynamically adjust the menu accordingly.

Here is a snippet of the PHP code I am working with to detect if a category has any published post associated with it, the basic model is :

```
php 
function has_published_posts($term_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE tt.term_id = %d
        AND tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'", 
    $term_id));

    return $post_count > 0;
}
```

***So far I am able to detect if a child-category or parent-category has any published post associated with it. This part is achieved.***

2- **However, I am currently searching how to hook into the new WordPress Navigation Block API to perform this filtering.** *I have been trying to find a relevant hook to access the Navigation Block API.*

***Does anyone know of a hook or method within the Navigation Block API that can be used to dynamically filter menu items ?***

I have seen there is Github and Wordpress pages that could help :

- https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0cb8475c0d07d23893b1d73d755eda5f12024585/src/wp-includes/blocks/navigation.php#L512
- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-block.php#L142
- https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/07/the-new-navigation-block/

If someone has some experience with filtering out the new Navigation Block, thanks for sharing your experience.

Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Would it be correct to rephrase the original goal as "I only want to show links to categories that have posts in my menu"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

Yes it is this, more precisely "I only want to show links to categories that have posts in 'publish' state in my menu", I correct right now, thanks. Do you have any idea by the way ?

Comment: Note that there have been a few attempts by core to figure out navigation blocks, and it would help to set some constraints, e.g. I assume you mean to do this only on the frontend in the rendered block? And that the site editor/block editor/REST API aren't a part of your question? I also assume that dynamically inserting categories is not an option? Have you tried the filters used for the classic `wp_nav_menu` function?

Comment: I see, 
In fact I am interested in any solution that would end up in displaying my menu in a up to date state. The simplest the better. 

I will give an another shot to wp_nav_menu. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the classic wp_nav_menu interface, it seems the last Navigation Bloc is great for ease of use, but for customization it seems to be less user friendly from an API/hook point of view.

I set this topic as answered.